# Using read() and write() system calls to access mmapped() memory

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I wish to ask whether is it possible to implement an mread() function using only system calls such as read() and write().  I know that the standard C library functions such as fread() and fwrite() use a type of buffer to read.  I want to do the same but this time I want to read() and write() from a buffer to a memory mapped region and vice versa. 
For example my mread() wants to read from memory map and store into buffer. Does it make sense to create a new fd just to use it as my TEMPORARY buffer.  Then I use read() to read from memory mapped region into the fd..and then use write() to store the contents in fd into my actual buff.
I hope I was clear :) ..Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why you don't use a simple memcpy?

Comment: As memcpy() is not a system call, am I right? It is a C Standard function....and we can only use system calls...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm asking why. Why do you have to use only system calls?

Comment: The reason is to understand how they actually work, as it is an assignment..

Comment: The buffer that fread and fwrite use is not managed using system calls, as far as I know. In fact fread uses read for more input that the data requested and places the data read in the buffer, and fwrite memcpy to a buffer and flush the buffer using write when it's full, or the file is closed or something like that. As you are using mmaped memory, you can modify it directly without system calls, and the data is saved to disk when OS thinks it's appropiate or when you request it explicitly using msync. If you want to do your own version or fread-fwrite don't use mmap.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope I was clear

Unfortunately, not very. But it sounds like you want to use the `pipe` system call. It opens two fds. Whatever's written on the write end can be read on the read end. If you're doing all of this in a single thread you have to be careful though, because you might run out of buffer space and the read/write call will then hang indefinitely.