# Reading a mapped file and storing it in a buffer

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Can someone kindly explain how I can implemented an mread function, by using the read() system call.  This method needs to read contents which are found in the mmapped file and read them into a buffer.  I have access to both the mmapped file and buffer by means of pointers. (i.e. void *addr and void *buff).

Your help is v.much appreciated.

Try so far:

```
int fd;

if ((fd = open("file.hole",O_RDWR, "rb")) < 0) {
    perror("create .hole file error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (write(fd, addr, count)!= count) {
    perror("Cannot write from address");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

buff = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char *));

if (read(fd, buff, count)) {
    perror("Cannot read from file descriptor to the buffer");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: int fd;
    
    if((fd = open("file.hole",O_RDWR, "rb")) < 0)
    {
        perror("create .hole file error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if(write(fd, addr, count)!= count)
    {
        perror("Cannot write from address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    buff = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
    
    if(read(fd, buff, count))
    {
        perror("Cannot read from file descriptor to the buffer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

Comment: Or maybe I can assign character by character such as the following code? 
buff = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
    
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = (char)addr[offset + i];
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350294/using-read-and-write-system-calls-to-access-mmapped-memory

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this might not a complete solution, but I don't have sufficient reputation to add only comments.

If you need to read data from mmaped file (assumed that you have called `mmap()` on a file), you don't need `read()` system call; you just need to copy the content from addr to buff.

If you need `read()` system call to copy data from a file to a buffer, you don't need `mmap()`; you should just do `open()` on the file to get an fd and then do `read()` data from the fd to the buffer.

Comment: So to copy the contents : would it be ok to do like this? :
buff = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char *)); for(int i = 0; i<count; i++) { buff[i] = (char)addr[offset + i]; }

Comment: You can use memcpy(buff, addr, ADDR_SIZE), where the ADDR_SIZE should be known when you call mmap().  By the way, the argument passed into malloc should be "count * sizeof(char)".